# highlight every other row knitr+Rmd

Tags: r, knitr

How can I highlight every other row of a table in knitr?  The output for the following .Rmd is an all white table rather than every other row grey:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
opts_chunk$set(cache=FALSE)
```
<style>
.myTable tr:nth-child(even) { /*(even) or (2n 0)*/
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
.myTable tr:nth-child(odd) { /*(odd) or (2n 1)*/
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>

<TABLE border=1 class="myTable">
<TR> <TH>  </TH> <TH> mpg </TH> <TH> cyl </TH> <TH> disp </TH>  </TR>
  <TR> <TD align="right"> Mazda RX4 </TD> <TD align="right"> 21.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 6.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 160.00 </TD> </TR>
  <TR> <TD align="right"> Mazda RX4 Wag </TD> <TD align="right"> 21.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 6.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 160.00 </TD> </TR>
  <TR> <TD align="right"> Datsun 710 </TD> <TD align="right"> 22.80 </TD> <TD align="right"> 4.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 108.00 </TD> </TR>
  <TR> <TD align="right"> Hornet 4 Drive </TD> <TD align="right"> 21.40 </TD> <TD align="right"> 6.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 258.00 </TD> </TR>
  <TR> <TD align="right"> Hornet Sportabout </TD> <TD align="right"> 18.70 </TD> <TD align="right"> 8.00 </TD> <TD align="right"> 360.00 </TD> </TR>
   </TABLE>
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<style>
.myTable tr:nth-child(even) td{ 
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
.myTable tr:nth-child(odd) td { 
    background: #FFFFFF;}

</style>
```

Your must add td to override the effect of the body.td declaration.